# lubuntu - change default window manager (awesome wm)

Tags: linux, window-manager, awesome-wm, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 14.10 and trying to change the default window manager to [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/).

I installed awesome with:

```
sudo apt-get install awesome
```

Per the [awesome wiki](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/My_first_awesome), I tried editing the ~/.xinitrc file to have the contents:

```
exec awesome
```

But after logging out (and rebooting) this isn't working.

Isn't there an rc file somewhere that I can edit?

My current need is for the awesome wm, but I was hoping there was a general way of doing this for any window manager.

Comment: When you say "this isn't working", do you mean Openbox is still your WM? Have you modified lubuntu's `autostart`? Have you tried `openbox --replace`? Doesn't `awesome` show up as a choice at login?

Comment: Yes, "not working" means that Openbox is still the wm. I wasn't aware of an "autostart" feature that can be altered. Will google that tonight.

Comment: Well, if you have a relatively vanilla Lubuntu, you should see it by clicking on Lxpanel's menu and choosing `Preferences` > `Default applications for LXSession`. While I use Lubuntu 14.04.02 myself, I log in to the Openbox session (just Openbox) rather than into the Lubuntu session (LXDE + Openbox).

Comment: @DKBose thanks... "Default applications for LXSession" worked by entering "awesome" and logging out/back in

Answer (score 0):

if You log out, after entering your login-name to log in again, you can chose the wm to use (probably right above your name, not sure because I do not use Lubuntu, but it is there somewhere). If you chose a wm that is not the default, you will get a notification asking you if you want to set it as your default and next time if you boot up your system you will have awesome.